# Play audio on drop (ios9 + jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, events, audio

I try play audio on finish of drag element.
Below code had worked fine on ios7, but on io9 doesn't work.

```
    $(function() {
        $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
        $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
                $("#Audio1").find('audio')[0].play();
            }
        });
    });
```

On Desktop it works too.

Somebody can help?